# Settings to use only Mic from a USB headset/mic combo, but not the speakers?

Tags: usb, headset

I have a USB headset/Mic combo device connected to my laptop(Vista Home edition). The laptop frontpanel has microphone input and speaker output.

While doing a skype call, I would like to use ,my USB microphone as audio input device instead of the Laptop mic & the Laptop speakers as audio output device instead of the USB headset speakers.

How can I get this setting done under Vista?

thank you.

-AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Skype, if you go to "Call" on the top menu, then click "Audio Settings," you will come to an options menu as seen below. You could select different speakers, such as your integrated laptop speakers. You could also turn the volume all the way down so that you cannot hear the speakers. There are other options if you hit the "Show advanced options" button that may help you too. These options can allow you to set up a priority of which speakers to use if they are connected.

-Hope this helps.

[image: Skype Options]